# Setup particular product tax in all countries

Tags: tax, csv, tax-class, tax-calculation, taxes

I want to add a 5% additional tax to a particular simple product in all countries. I looked into Fixed Product Tax, but that only allows to choose from one country at a time. If I wanted to add the product tax in all countries for a particular product, I would have to manually add 200 countries to the FPT. Similar situation with Tax Rules and Tax Rates. My initial idea was to loop over all countries and add them to the taxable product through code or use a CSV, but this seems like complicating a simple problem. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There doesnt seem to be a quick and easy solution for this, but what worked for me was creating a new Tax Class in Stores > Tax Rules > Add New Tax Rule > Advanced and importing a CSV with all 250 countries and appropriate tax settings. Then apply this Tax Class to the product.